# React, createContext default value problem with useState hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-context, react-state

In my React application with TypeScript, I want to create a context for a component. The `createContext` shows an error when a default value is not provided. One of the values I want to pass is the `setFilters` which is a hook dispatcher. How should I provide a default value?

Also, I do not want it optional, to prevent `!` from invocation.

```js
    export interface ContextProps {
      filters: FiltersType;
      setFilters: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<FiltersType>>;
    }
    
    export const MyContext = React.createContext<ContextProps>({
      filters: defaultFilters, // imported from constants holder
      setFilters: // <---- What should be here?
    });
    
    const FiltersContext: React.FC<IProps> = (props: IProps) => {
      const [filters, setFilters] = React.useState<FiltersType>(defaultFilters);
    
      return <MyContext.Provider value={{ filters, setFilters }}>{props.children}</MyContext.Provider>;
    };
    
    export default FiltersContext;
```

Answer (score 6):

The default value is used when no context provider is available, so it depends what do you want to do in such situation. You can throw an error, then use `setFilters: () => { throw new Error('No FiltersContext available'); }`, or silently ignore it, then `setFilters: () => {}` would do, or whatever you want to do.

Answer (score 4):

You can use just a simple function for its default value like this:

```
export const MyContext = React.createContext<ContextProps>({
  filters: defaultFilters, // imported from constants holder
  setFilters: () => null
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to just **set the function as optional** using `?`  like:

```
 export interface ContextProps {
      filters: FiltersType;
      setFilters?: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<FiltersType>> | ((fiters: FiltersType) => {});
    }
```

This way you don't even have to set a default value for the setState functions

---

Another way would be to **add an alternate typing**, an empty function that takes the same arguments that your `setState` would. Then set the default value to that alternate.

So in your example what i'd do is the following *(note the underscore `_filters` to tell ts that the argument will not be used)*:

```
   export interface ContextProps {
      filters: FiltersType;
      setFilters: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<FiltersType>> | ((fiters: FiltersType) => {});
    }
    
    export const MyContext = React.createContext<ContextProps>({
      filters: defaultFilters, // imported from constants holder
      setFilters: (_filters: FiltersType) => {}
    });
    
    const FiltersContext: React.FC<IProps> = (props: IProps) => {
      const [filters, setFilters] = React.useState<FiltersType>(defaultFilters);
    
      return <MyContext.Provider value={{ filters, setFilters }}>{props.children}</MyContext.Provider>;
    };
    
    export default FiltersContext;
```